# Spring @Transactional breaking application for embedded and standalone MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using `Spring Data MongoDB 2.2.1.RELEASE` for MongoDB access. And `flapdoodle embed mongo 2.2.0` as embedded MongoDB for testing. This setup works fine. But recently, I have added support for Spring transactions. And since, MongoDB supports transactions only on replica sets. I have created a replica set locally on my machine and tested transaction scenarios. All good till now. But now when I run my unit tests, `@Transactional` annotation added to service methods is breaking the application with below error since the embedded MongoDB is not a replica set.

> com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected

My question is how to configure my application so the `@Transactional` feature does not break my application when using embedded or standalone MongoDB?

Suggestions much appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Do you use the updated API to connect to the MongoDB? From the package `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient`?

Comment: @Nikolas No, I think. I am using `MongoTransactionManager`. I read about it but couldn't find any samples for it. How does it help with transaction support for embedded and standalone MongoDB?

Comment: Would you provide the code that connects to MongoDB? We might find something out.

Comment: @Nikolas am using Spring Data `MongoOperations` for connecting to MongoDB.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary I am also facing this error, did you find any workaround for this without changing much code?

Comment: @ChandanGawri The only possible solutions it seems is what Oleg has suggested. I didn't try it though. Have disabled transactions for now.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Ok, I just need some reference to enable 1-node replica set  for embedded mongo.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run a 1-node replica set. You may consider this especially in tests so that your test environment more closely resembles your production one.